# $.noty is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, noty

A page on my site uses Noty to display notifications. I'm loading Noty 2.4.1 (jquery-noty) and jQuery 3.5.1 from a CDN (cdnjs) and I show notifications like this:

```
$.noty({text, timeout, type, layout});
```

This configuration has been working fine ever since I first set up that code, but now, without any change from me, I get the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.noty is not a function

Indeed, if I go to the console and type `$.noty`, I see an object, but if I type `$.noty()` I get:

> TypeError: $.noty is not a function

Browsers tested:

- Firefox 84.0.2 (32-bit)
- Microsoft Edge 88.0.705.50

This is really strange as I haven't touched that code in a long time. Could they have implemented some breaking change to the version served via CDN? What can be done to make Noty 2.4.1 work again?

On CodeSandbox you can find a [reproducible example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-65871715-7un25?file=/index.html).

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] (including the HTML you use to load the two libraries and your own JS which depends on them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Noty is 3, and I simply ported my existing configuration from 2 to 3 by calling it like this:

```
new Noty({text, timeout, type, layout}).show();
```